# Compiling the project using libuv with CMake

Tags: c, cmake

I have got a small async udp server - [RiDE](https://github.com/koshinus/C_programs/tree/master/diploma).

And i can't build it with CMake. When i trying to i get errors:

```
undefined reference to 'uv_default_loop'
undefined reference to 'uv_udp_init'
...(other libuv functions)
```

But when i build it with command like this:

```
gcc -std=c11 RiDE_server.h RiDE_server.cpp main.cpp -o main.x -Wall -luv
```

everything is ok.

I think that the problem is in src/CMakeLists.txt file, but i can't understand how to fix it. Path to libuv headers on my machine - /usr/include. Path to libuv shared libs - /usr/lib/x86-64-linux-gnu.

Comment: You do ***link*** with the `uv` library in your project? How do you add the `uv` library in your `CMakeLists.txt`? Can you please show it?

Comment: Also, please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude What commands do you mean when saying _link_?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `make VERBOSE=1`.  What linker command does it run?  It must be missing `-luv`.  To fix that, add something like this to your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
target_link_libraries(foo uv)
```

Comment: Thanks! I use `set( CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -luv")` instead of `target_link_libraries` but it doesn't work for some reason.